# Searching and changing a string in text file (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

I searched a lot in the internet and I didn't find an appropriate code that searches for a string in a certain text file and replaces it with a different word?

Would appreciate help.. And thanks for the helpers!!

Let's say that the name of the text file is `fruits`and it has the following contents:

```
watermelon
banana
apple orange
```

And I want to replace the string `"orange"` in the string `"grapes"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open the file for reading and writing using the built-in [open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Then read all its contents and replace `orange` with `grapes` using [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Now set the offset to `0` with the [seek-method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) because you want to override the contents. 
After that write the result to the file.

```
myfile = 'fruits.txt' # Replace this with the path to your file

with open(myfile, 'r+') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    result = contents.replace('orange', 'grapes')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(result)
```

Example usage:

```
$ echo -e "watermelon\nbanana\napple orange" > fruits.txt
$ python test.py
$ cat fruits.txt
watermelon
banana
apple grapes
```